# Get most recent plugged in USB device

Tags: usb-device

I want to make a script that displays the latest usb devices plugged into the computer, but not all of them.

I am using Arch Linux.

Do you have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: place a file to `/etc/udev/rules.d`

Comment: `dmesg` has this info

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Note that the amount of info available depends on whether the kernel configuration option `CONFIG_USB_ANNOUNCE_NEW_DEVICES` was enabled at compile-time or not.

Comment: @telcoM Enabled in CentOS/RHEL, Fedora, Debian and Ubuntu. I don't care much about other distros.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Even those distributions can have a custom-built kernel, which may have non-essential configuration options disabled.  And when considering build-from-source distributions like Gentoo and Arch, I basically treat them as always having a custom-built kernel.